# Dart null safety breaks animated builder

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am getting this error in Animated Builder after I enable dart null safety in my flutter because one of my plugin needs it.

```
return AnimatedBuilder(
            //animation is done here
          animation:_pageController,
          builder: (BuildContext context,Widget widget){
          double value = 1;
            if(_pageController.position.haveDimensions){
              value = _pageController.page! - index;
              value = (1-(value.abs()*0.25)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
            }
           return Center(
               child: SizedBox(
                 height:Curves.easeInOut.transform(value)*380.0,
                 child: widget,
                 ),
              );
          },
```

I get error like this:

> The argument type 'Center Function(BuildContext, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)'.

Before I enable dart null safety in pubspec.yaml it was fine.

Comment: I think it will work if you just change `Widget` to `Widget?` in the line where you define `builder` since `child` in `SizedBox` is allowed to take a `Widget?` as parameter.

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer based on that. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the parameter `builder` in `AnimatedBuilder`, takes a `TransitionBuilder` function with the following signature:

```
Widget TransitionBuilder (
    BuildContext context,
    Widget? child
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionBuilder.html

In Dart 2.12 with null-safety, `Widget?` means that `child` can point to an object of the type `Widget` or `null`. But in your case you have a method with the signature:

```
Widget (BuildContext context,Widget widget)
```

Where `Widget` means it will always point to a `Widget` object and can therefore never be `null`. This signature is therefore not compatible with the required signature for `builder`.

In your case, the fix is rather simple since you are only using the argument `widget` to forward it into the `child` argument in the `SizedBox` constructor. This constructor has the following signature:

```
const SizedBox(
    {Key? key,
    double? width,
    double? height,
    Widget? child}
)
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.html

As you can see, `child` is typed to be `Widget?` and does therefore allow `null` as a value. So you can just change the argument type of the method you give as the `builder` argument to:

```
          builder: (BuildContext context,Widget? widget){
```

Comment: I typically let the compiler infer the proper types for those, unless it guesses wrong or weird.  I save typing (intentional overload) that way.